# Display Modal from JQuery in Laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal

Model not popping up when click on day in calendar.
I am using the FullCalendar.io in Laravel and now I am trying to get a modal with four separate forms attached to the modal. Here is the code and I am trying to display the modal inside the script with JQuery.

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('title', '| Calendar')

@section('stylesheets')
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/header.css') }}"></link>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{{ URL::asset('assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css') }}" /> 
@endsection

@section('scripts')
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js') }}"></script>
@endsection

@section('navlinks')
    <li><a class="active" href="athletecalendar"><i class="fa fa-map fa"></i>Calendar</a></li>
    <li><a href="goals"><i class="fa fa-home fa"></i>Goals</a></li>
    <li><a href="schedule"><i class="fa fa-map fa"></i>Schedule</a></li>
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-black">Logs</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0;">
                    <a href="#">Training</a>
                    <a href="#">Notes</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addTraining"> + Training </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNote"> + Note</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h1>Calendar</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Training Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="addTraining" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Training</h4>
                </div>
                <!--Training Tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabContent">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#strength" data-toggle="tab">Strength</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#endurance" data-toggle="tab">Endruance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#flexibility" data-toggle="tab">Flexibility</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#balance" data-toggle="tab">Balance</a><li>
                </ul>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <!-- Strength Tab in Modal-->
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="strength">
                            @yield('strength')
                        </div>
                        <!-- Endruance Tab in Modal-->
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="endurance">
                            @yield('endurance')
                        </div>
                        <!-- Flexibility Tab in Modal-->
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="flexibility">
                            @yield('flexibility')
                        </div>
                        <!-- Balance Tab in Modal-->
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="balance">
                            @yield('balance')
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Note Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="addNote" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Note</h4>
                </div>
                <!--Notes Tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabContent">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#training" data-toggle="tab">Training</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nutrition" data-toggle="tab">Nutrition</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#medical" data-toggle="tab">Medical</a><li>
                </ul>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <!-- Training Tab in Modal-->
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="training">
                            @yield('trainingNotes')
                        </div>
                        <!-- Nutrition Tab in Modal-->
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="nutrition">
                            @yield('nutritionNotes')
                        </div>
                        <!-- Medical Tab in Modal-->
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="medical">
                            @yield('medicalNotes')
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="calendar"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var BASEURL = "{{ url('/') }}";
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        navLinks: true,
        editable: false,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(date){
           date = moment(date.format());
           //$('#date').val(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
           $('#addTraining').modal('toggle');
//             alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
//             $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        },
        events: BASEURL + '/events',
        eventSources: [
        {
            events: [ // put the array in the `events` property
                {
                    title  : 'event1',
                    start  : '2017-06-01'
                },
                {
                    title  : 'event2',
                    start  : '2017-06-05',
                    end    : '2017-06-07'
                },
                {
                    title  : 'event3',
                    start  : '2017-06-09T12:30:00',
                }
            ],
            color: 'black',     // an option!
            textColor: 'yellow' // an option!
        }

        // any other event sources...

        ]
            });
        });
</script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this `jQuery.noConflict();` right before `$('#addTraining').modal('toggle');`